# How to properly define associations in Entity Framework 6 - Database first?

Tags: sql, .net, database, entity-framework

I am fairly new to working with EF.

I have some question that might be very basic.

I have a database and from this database i am generating my object model(database first).

When the object model generation is complete i double click my .edmx file and get a complete overview of my tables and their associations.

My problem is that all associations are 1 to *. Some of the relations needs to be e.g. 1 to 0-1,

My question is: How can i be sure that the entity framework is generated with the correct associations? I guess this must somehow be defined in the sql creating the table?

At the moment i need to reconfigure all associations each time i update the model from database because it creates the wrong associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your relationships are set up properly. I prefer to create a Database Diagram in SQL Server Management Studio to inspect and manage table relationships.

If I ever adjust a relationship or column on a table in a data base and need to update the model I will delete that table from the .edmx file and then add it back. In your case it sounds like everything is wrong so I would delete everything from the .edmx file and add back the tables with the proper relationships.

Comment: Hi thanks for the explanation and suggestions. I will try to do that in SQL Server Management Studio. Even though John Hartsock gives a very good explanation too i will mark this as answer because u were the first to write.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few types of associations and if your working DB first then your database is controlling the associations.  Below are a few.

- **1 to 0 or many:**
    This is constructed when you create a foreign key to a field
- **1 to 0..1:**
    This is constructed when you create a foreign key between two primary keys
- **many to many:**
  This is constructed when you build a true association table between that contains only the primary keys from both tables.

I can only assume from your description that EF does not generate the relationships the way you expect because your Foreign keys are not setup accurately.